# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/w9/1zsm5zp53jn8c0n0l4zrhzj40000gn/T/pip-build-mphahblv/http

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip, osx-elcapitan

I have problem while trying to install package **http** using pip3:

```
$ pip3 install http
```

result is:

```
Collecting http
  Using cached http-0.02.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/w9/1zsm5zp53jn8c0n0l4zrhzj40000gn/T/pip-build-mphahblv/http/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import http
      File "/private/var/folders/w9/1zsm5zp53jn8c0n0l4zrhzj40000gn/T/pip-build-mphahblv/http/http/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from request import Request
    ImportError: No module named 'request'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/w9/1zsm5zp53jn8c0n0l4zrhzj40000gn/T/pip-build-mphahblv/http
```

Comment: given that the 3.x stdlib already has an http module, it seems slightly strange to be installing another with the same name.

Comment: I cannot help you, but from today I am not able to install any package using pip in my mac os X.  Exactly the same error as you:  code 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pip install requests first